# NTAG 21x PWD_AUTH or other native commands using PC/SC via ACR123U

Tags: c#, nfc, native, pcsc, ntag21x

I am implementing a new system using C#/UWP which uses NTAG 21x tags with password protection to store some information. I use different readers from ACS and access them via their PC/SC interface like shown in the following example from Microsoft: https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=nfcsmartcardreader
Read/Write by using the standard commands works fine, but executing the `PWD_AUTH` (or `GET_VERSION`/`READ_SIG`) command is tricky.

Using an ACR12**2**U I could successfully execute them via "Direct Transmit" to the embedded PN532 like explained in here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44243037/472434

But for the ACR12**3**U I still can't find a solution.
I already found out that this device uses the [RC531](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/MFRC531.pdf), but I neither can find similar communication commands for that chip like for the PN532 nor can I find "Direct Transmit" commands for the ACR123U.

Can I somehow execute such native commands with the ACR123U?
Or can I use something like APDU-wrapping like explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41729534/472434)?
Or are there even PC/SC commands available which should perform at least the `PWD_AUTH` command on NTAG21x tags?

Comment: Are you able to found anything related to ACR123U?

Comment: @hellowahab Yes, I found a solution. Main problem was an outdated firmware - what version does your reader have?

Comment: Thanks @ChrFin. We are able to read and write on ACR123U using an SKD intended for ACR122U. It worked and working fine.